# HTML5 Meter Styling in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I want to style a password strength meter implemented via . It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Here is the relevant CSS, taken from the [GitHub project CSS file](https://github.com/mslinn/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/public/styles/main.css#L52-L82):

```
meter {
    /* Reset the default appearance */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;

    margin: 0 auto 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: .5em;

    /* Applicable only to Firefox */
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

meter[value="0"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value,
meter[value="1"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: red; }
meter[value="2"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: yellow; }
meter[value="3"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: orange; }
meter[value="4"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: green; }

meter[value="1"]::-moz-meter-bar,
meter[value="1"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: red; }
meter[value="2"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: yellow; }
meter[value="3"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: orange; }
meter[value="4"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: green; }
```

The last bit is important, the ability to style based on the meter's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an intentional behavior change.
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5668635896971264

So, you need to remove `-webkit-appearance:none`, or need to build a meter value box yourself.

```
<style>
meter {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: gray;
}
meter > div {
  height: 100%;
}
meter[value="1"] > div {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
}
meter[value="2"] > div {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
meter[value="3"] > div {
  width: 75%;
  background: orange;
}
meter[value="4"] > div {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
</style>
<meter value=3><div></div></meter>
```

Comment: This works on Chrome for Windows and Mac, just not for Linux. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632171

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Marked as fixed as of version `52` (Jul 29, 2016), can anyone confirm this? It seems, it still does not work on Linux